# The type signature […] lacks an accompanying binding

Tags: haskell

Why do I end up with "binding" errors in the following program?

```
wheels :: Int

cars :: Int

carpark wheels cars   
  | wheels   == odd      = error wheels "is not even"
  | cars     <= 0        = error cars "is an invalid number"
  | (2*cars) >= wheels   = error "the number of wheels is invalid"
  | wheels   >= (4*cars) = error "the number of wheels is invalid"
  | otherwise            = "There are " (wheels-(2 * cars)) `div` 2 "cars and " (cars - ((wheels - (2 * cars)) div 2)) "motorcycles on the parking lot"
```

This is the error:

```
 aufgabe1.lhs:6:3:
The type signature for ‘wheels’ lacks an accompanying binding

aufgabe1.lhs:7:3:
The type signature for ‘cars’ lacks an accompanying binding
```

How can I get rid of it?

Comment: You shouldn't write separate type signatures for the function arguments. All you need is `carPark :: Int -> Int -> String`, which is the type signature for `carPark`.

Comment: watch out - you need the "toString" method `show` to convert `Int` to `String` and the concatenation operator `++` to combine these strings

Answer (score 13):

## What are missing bindings?

There are many problems with your program, but lets focus on the "binding" one first. You're probably accustomed to Pascal or C, where you have to specify the type of the argument at the argument:

```c
string carpark(int wheels, int cars);
```

However, Haskell doesn't work like this. If you write

```
wheels :: Int
```

in your document, you're telling the compiler that the value `wheels` will have the type `Int`. The compiler now expects a definition somewhere. This definition—it's binding—is missing. The **type** of `wheels` is known, but it's not known what **value** `wheels` should be **bound** to.

If you were to add

```
wheels = 1 * 2 + 12312
```

the compiler wouldn't complain about that particular binding anymore.

## What's the actual problem?

As I've conclused above, you want to specify the arguments' types of `carpark`, right? However, this concludes that you specify **`carpark`'s** type:

```
carpark :: Int -> Int -> String
carpark wheels cars 
   | -- omitted
```

This will get rid of the "missing bindings" errors.

## What's missing?

Well, after this, you will still have a non-compiling piece of software, for example `error wheels "is not even"` isn't valid. Have a look at `error`'s type:

```
error :: String -> a
```

Since `wheels` isn't a `String`, this won't compile. Instead, you have to `show` `wheels`:

```
error (show wheels ++ " is not even")
```

Note that `error (show wheels) " is not even"` will happily compile, but won't give you the error message you're actually looking for, so beware of parenthesis and string concatenation.

## Exercises

- Write a function `whatNumber` that returns "Is Odd" if the number is odd and "Is Even" if the number is even, e.g.

  ```
  whatNumber 2 == "Is Even"
  ```
- Write a function `whatNumberId`, that returns `"<x> is odd"` if the number is odd and `"<x> is even"` if the number is even, where `<x>` should be the number, e.g.

  ```
  whatNumberId 123 == "123 is odd"
  ```

Both exercises should help you to accomplish your original task.

Answer (score 1):

Zeta's answer is complete, but I would like to make just another point, which unfortunately doesn't fit in a comment.

```
wheels :: Int
cars :: Int
carpark wheels cars...
```

This attempt at code in Haskell is somewhat analogous to the following code snippet in C:

```
int wheels;
int cars;
char* carpark(wheels, cars) { ... }
```

Where does the analogy lie? In both cases, the first and the second occurrences of `wheels` (or `cars`) are referring to different objects. The first one refers to a global variable, and the second one refers to the function's formal parameter.

Inside `carpark`, `wheels` denotes the function's formal parameter; the global `wheels` is not available due to name hiding. Note that in C99 and later, this code would be illegal because formal parameters of `carpark` are not given types. The fact that a global `wheels` was given the type `int` means nothing, because that `wheels` has nothing to do with `wheels` in `carpark`.

These general ideas of **scopes of identifiers** apply in Haskell, too. The declaration `wheels :: Int` declares a value at its scope (presumably, module scope), and `carpark wheels cars` uses the same name for another value in a nested scope. You cannot access the outer `wheels` in the body of `carpark` because it is hidden; had you written `carpark w c...` instead, you would have access to both outer `wheels` and local `w`.

Finally, while in the C snippet above the lack of types for `wheels` and `cars` constitutes an error, in Haskell we usually leave it to the compiler to deduce the types of formal parameters. `carpark` itself is a value, so it has a type. If we declare the type as `carpark :: Int -> Int -> String`, the compiler deduces that, in a definition that starts with `carpark wheels cars...`, `wheels` here cannot be but of type `Int`.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that I've seen a language where you would write the arguments and their types first, and then the actual function. But I can't recall its name.